# solr optimize command and concurrency

Tags: solr

I know that when Solr performs optimization, either explicitly by the optimize command, or implicitly by Lucene due to the mergeFactor, readers are not blocked. That is, the server is still available for searching

Is it also available for updates? Can other threads in my application send documents updates to solr, and possibly also send commits? Will those updates pass through into the index, or will they be blocked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An old question though, however, some more info can help here.

optimize command in solr is a call to IndexWriter's forceMerge() method. This method does take a lock on the IndexWriter instance itself. However, the point is that adding documents does not require any lock on the IW instance, neither does it need any commitLock or fullFlushLock.
Moreover, even with forceMerge(), it is the ConcurrentMergeScheduler which picks up the merge process and does it in a different thread altogether.

Usually merge process (Not the forceMerge, which is not recommended anyway) needs to lock the IndexWriter instance only while preparing the merge info, when it needs to know what segments to take for merge, and what is the new merged segment name etc. Once it has this information, merge happens concurrently.

So, yes, you can keep adding documents even when optimize is in process - they will get buffered in RAM until the next commit/optimize or close() of IndexWriter.

Having said that, might as well add that you can not have concurrent commits to different segments - that is Lucene will do only one commit at a time. Adding documents does not flush them to any segment at all - just puts them in buffer.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is "Yes".  The server will be respond to search requests, but updated documents will not show up in the search results until you send a `commit` command.  The updated documents will stack up and be committed whenever a client/thread issues a `commit` command to the server.  If you have multiple clients/threads issuing `updates` and `commits` they will not block each other, and the updates will show as soon as the `commit` command completes.